# Mobile Safari Redirects to App Store

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

According to [several](http://www.tuaw.com/2014/06/18/ios-8-safari-can-block-ads-from-automatically-redirecting-to-the/) [news](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/06/ios-8-beta-2-whats-new.html) [stories](http://www.macstories.net/roundups/ios-8-tips-tricks-and-details/), the iOS 8 betas included a new feature:

> Safari now blocks ads from automatically redirecting to the App Store without user interaction.

(The last link makes it look like the feature did get into the released version of iOS 8, not just the betas.)

However, certain sites (with ads) are still managing to open the App Store on my iPhone 5S.

Is there a way to ensure this setting is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately regardless of Apple's efforts to curb websites redirecting users to the iTunes App Store, it still regularly occurs.

There is no 'setting' which enables / disables this 'feature', my only recommendation would be to ensure the "Fraudulent Website Warning" is switched on, having the "Block Cookies" setting on anything but 'always allow' and also testing weather turing off JavaScript support (under Advanced) helps in any way.